# How long is the sunrise (or sunset) on North (or South) Pole?

Tags: the-sun, time, velocity, sunrise, sunset

I wonder how to calculate the duration of the Sun crossing the line of the horizon on equinox on Pole. For equator I used this formula:

$t = \frac{2 \times p}{\cos(\phi) \times u}$, where $u$ - is velocity of the Sun in the sky ($15'$ per minute), $p$ is Sun's visual diameter ($30'$), $\phi$ - latitude of observer

On equator everything is easy:

$\cos(0) = 1$

But on Pole:

$\cos(90) = 0$, but I can't divide by zero.

Is there any other formula?

[image: I used this drawing]

Comment: Sunrise/set at the poles depends on the Sun's changing declination

Comment: The duplicate gives an an answer (32hr 50 min) and explains why.

Comment: I know that declination of the Sun is zero as it is equinox